# url slideshow using css

Tags: css, image, url, slider

[image]I am relatively new to coding and am trying to create a very simple slideshow only I want the javascript to be "linked" to my image url's in the css rather than using div id's for the images in html. Can this be done because I can't seem to figure it out.

Basically, my website has a series of image thumbnails that currently expand when clicked upon, thus a vertical accordion feature. The accordion is its own div id and everything to do with the accordion is kept within a div class "container" and the images, specifically, are within a div class "wrapper". All of the text and links are within the body of the html and the images are all in css.

I understand how to create a image slideshow (just rotating images, no clickable images/links) in the html and the slideshow works when I moved an image from the css into the html. However, after doing this, the image is no longer within the "rules" of the accordion. Thus the image that I move into the html rotates, but is overlapping the text and is no longer an image slice like the rest of the accordion. I can move the slideshow image around on the page using css, but it still overlaps the text and other features within the accordion.

I've even tried moving the images in the html around to different locations within the body to see if the problem was related to where the images were placed, but this did not solve the problem.

So is there a way to use javascript and keep the images in the css so the accordion features are also maintained? I am stuck with this and don't know what to try next. Thanks.

```
<body>
<div class="container">
<h1 class="va-name"><a href="avatest.html"> Amy Danielsons</a>                          </h1>
<h2 class="va-contact">Contact</h2>
<h3 class="va-resume"><a href="resume.html">Resume</a>
<h4 class="va-about">About</h4>
<h5 class="va-port"><a href="#">Online Portfolio</h5>
<h6 class="va-hatch"><img src="images/pattern.png" width="10"       height="10"     alt="hatch" />
</h6>

<div id="va-accordion" class="va-container">

            <div class="va-nav">
                <span class="va-nav-prev">Previous</span>
                <span class="va-nav-next">Next</span>
            </div>

            <div class="va-wrapper">
                <div class="va-slice va-slice-1">
                <!--slider 1 images -->

                <div>
                <img src="images/testa.jpg" />
                </div>

                <div>
                <img src="images/testb.jpg" />
                </div>

                <div>
                <img src="images/testc.jpg" />
                </div>

                    <h3 class="va-title">Cranbrook</h3>
                    <div class="va-content">
                        <p>Paragraph Title</p>
                        <p2>dolor sit amet, consectetur      adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi. Nulla quis sem at nibh elementum imperdiet. Duis sagittis ipsum.</p2>

                    </div>
                </div>
              </div>
```

(css portion below: you can see where I deleted the url for the first image slice and moved the image (and added 2 more images) into the html above)

```
}
.va-slice-1{
background:#FFF
}
.va-slice-2{
background:#FFF url(../images/2d/liz.jpg) no-repeat center center;
}
.va-slice-3{
background:#FFF url(../images/2d/oldcar.jpg) no-repeat center center;
}
```

Comment: I've read this about three times now, and I still can't work out what you want your page to actually do. Can you draw a diagram?

Comment: I don't really know how to draw a diagram of what I'm asking. But I can try and explain it a little better. All I want to do is make an image slideshow all within css instead of html. I want to use the urls within the css to link the slideshow images to the javascript for the slideshow instead of using div id's for the images in html. I don't know if this is even possible?

Comment: The image above shows the basic accordion idea. When you click on one of the image slices, it expands to show the full image with some text on toward the left of the image. All I want to do is have the enlarged image roll through a series of related images as a slide show while you're reading about it.

Comment: The problem is, the accordion I've been using keeps all the images within the css page, not the hmtl and the only way I can get the slideshow to work is by moving the images into the html as div id's. This results the accordion breaking because the image I moved to the html will no longer abide by the rules of the accordion. The picture above shows this: The top image slice is the only image that has the slideshow effect added (in the html because I don't know how to do it any other way).

Comment: You want the URL in Javascript? Like $('img').attr('href') ? that would give your the url for the image into a Javascript var to use. Can you provide a url to a demo or something so we can see more code?

Comment: yes, I am trying to upload the website now, so I can paste a link. I know that if you open it in Firefox, you can right click, Inspect Element, and see all the code. I hope to have it up soon.

Comment: okay, I am having some technical difficulties with uploading the site, but will try and put up a link as soon as possible. As the Alex Reynolds comment, I think that's exactly what I'm trying to do. Should I put the image url from the css within the 'img' of the java? For example: $('../images/dd/oldcar.jpg).attr('href'). Also do  I need to put the actual image in as the 'href'? I think I need some more help on what you're suggesting. Can you give a more specific example of what I should do? Thanks.

Comment: @alexreynolds, here's the link for the site: http://homepages.uc.edu/~daniela8/

Answer (score 0):

> So is there a way to use javascript and keep the images in the css so the accordion features are also maintained?

To keep the images in the CSS, use an inline style attribute. Instead of

```
            <div>
            <img src="images/testb.jpg" />
            </div>
```

Use

```
<div class="image-wrap" style="background: url(images/testb.jpg)"></div>
```

then set the correct height and width for `.image-wrap` either using javascript, or in your stylesheet.

Comment: You should create a jsfiddle example, too. That would make it easier to help you!

Comment: How do I get more than one image for the slideshow? In your example above, it looks like you only have one image within the url. Do I need to create multiple url lists? Or could you show an example of what your code would look like with multiple images?

Comment: here's the revised inline style attribute. How do I get more than one picture for the slideshow? Your example only allows for one image?  'code' <div id="va-accordion" class="va-container">
    
       <div class="va-nav">
     <span class="va-nav-prev">Previous</span>
     <span class="va-nav-next">Next</span>
    </div>
                
                <div class="va-wrapper">
     <div class="va-slice va-slice-1">
                    <!--slider 1 images -->
                   
                <div class="image-wrap" style="background: url(../images/2d/liz.jpg)"></div>

Answer (score 0):

Though I, like others, don't entirely understand your situation, [this article](http://webdevel.blogspot.com/2009/07/jquery-quick-tip-extract-css-background.html?m=1) explains how to grab the background-image's URL if you are using jQuery.

Essentially it parses
    $('img').css('background-image');

To set the URL, use
    $('img').css('background-image', 'url:("http://www.example.com/image.png")');